# array_slice by two associative indexes

Tags: php, arrays, slice

what is the simplest way to get an array slice between two associative keys in PHP?

for example, for the array

```
$arr = array('2012-02-01'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-02-02'=> 'bla blah',
'2013-02-03'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-02-04'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-02-05'=> 'bla blah',
'2010-03-06'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-04-07'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-01-08'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-02-09'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-10-10'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-12-03'=> 'bla blah');
```

How can one get a slice of everything between key: '2012-02-04' and key '2012-04-07'
which would be:

```
array('2012-02-04'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-02-05'=> 'bla blah',
'2010-03-06'=> 'bla blah',
'2012-04-07'=> 'bla blah')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're certain that both keys are in the array:

```
$arr = array(
    '2012-02-01'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-02-02'=> 'bla blah',
    '2013-02-03'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-02-04'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-02-05'=> 'bla blah',
    '2010-03-06'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-04-07'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-01-08'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-02-09'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-10-10'=> 'bla blah',
    '2012-12-03'=> 'bla blah'
);
$startKey = '2012-02-04';
$endKey = '2012-02-07';

$new = array_slice(
    $arr,
    array_search($startKey, array_keys($arr)),
    array_search($endKey, array_keys($arr)) - 
        array_search($startKey, array_keys($arr)) + 1
);
var_dump($new);
```

else you'll need to do a bit of validation on the returns from the array_search() calls before doing the array_slice()

Comment: I'm using a big array. is there perhaps a way to do this without calling array_keys 3 times? also did not work. missed the last 2 keys

Comment: Yes there is, call it twice outside of the array_slice() and store the results in variables and then just use those variables in the array_slice().... you can also eliminate a further array() keys call by calling it once and storing the result in a variable, etc.